# VScode debugger fails to halt at breakpoints on Windows11 computer - possible solutions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

VScode debugger does not stop on breakpoints. I have been working with VScode developing a calculator program in Javascript for over 2 years on my Windows10 desktop and laptop computers with no problems. About 2 weeks ago my Windows10 desktop computer dropped dead, so I bought a new desktop with Windows11. VScode ran fine except for the fact that it did not stop at breakpoints. I struggled through it for 3 days trying all sorts of tips on the Web and finally got it to work. It worked fine for one whole day. The next day I powered the computer back on and the problem reappeared by itself. I changed nothing from one day to the next. How can that happen?

I tried different settings of Launch.json and Settings.json files several times. I also tried reloading VScode and Chrome extensions several times. I also tried copying Launch.json and Chrome extension files from my Windows10 Laptop (VScode stops at breakpoints on my Laptop) and that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that VScode updated, and the debugger became incompatible with windows 11. Try downloading previous version of the program. If that doesn’t work, try downloading another code editor. That will surely work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).